# accelerometer measuring negative peaks of velocity

Tags: objective-c, xcode, accelerometer, velocity

I'm writing an application for iphone4 and I'm taking values from the accelerometer to compute the current movement from a known initial position.

I've noticed a very strange behavior: often times when I walk holding the cellphone for a few meters and then I stop, I register a negative peak of **overall velocity** when the handset decelarates.  How is that possible if I keep moving in the same direction?

To compute the variation in velocity I just do this:

```
delta_v = (acc_previous + acc_now)/2 * (1/(updating_frequency))
```

Comment: I wanted to stress the fact that when I'm delecerating (*and moving in the same direction as before*) the velocity not only goes to 0, but it goes negative. That's the behavior I can't explain. It should stop at 0, otherwise that would mean a change in direction, which doesn't happen.

Comment: And of course:
 velocity_now += delta_v

Answer (score 2):

Say you are moving at a constant 10 m/s.  Your acceleration is zero.  Let's say, for the sake of simplicity, you sample every 1 second.

If you decelerate smoothly over a period of 0.1 seconds, you might get a reading of 100 m/s/s or you might not get a reading at all since the deceleration might fall between two windows.  Your formula most likely will not detect any deceleration or if it does, you'll get two values of -50 m/s/s: (0 - 100) / 2  and then (-100 + 0) / 2.  Either way you'll get the wrong final velocity.

Something similar could happen at almost any scale, All you need is a short period of high acceleration or deceleration that you happen to sample and your figures are screwed.

Comment: @Ricky:  Sorry, I don't, except to sample as frequently as possible.  Ultimately, the accelerometers are not designed for inertial navigation.

Comment: What I'm now considering is to keep the first "big peak" I get and discard the next one. That would allow me, in theory, to both find in which the direction I'm moving and my current displacement.
Of course I'll have to decide what "big" means...

Comment: One thing isn't clear to me. I'm sampling every 1/60 of a second. That's not even 0.02s. How can that be not small enough to capture the movement of a person taking a couple of steps in one direction?  I tried with a frequency of 100 a second and while curves seem to be smoother, they're still there messing everything up.

Answer (score 2):

Numerical integration is hard.  Naive numerical integration of a noisy signal will essentially *always* produce significant errors and drift (like what you're seeing).  People have come up with all sorts of clever ways to deal with this problem, most of which require having some source of reference information other than the accelerometer (think of a Wii controller, which has not only an accelerometer, but also the thingy on top of the TV).

Note that any MEMS accelerometer is necessarily limited to reporting only a certain band of accelerations; if acceleration goes outside of that band, then you will absolutely get significant drift unless you have some way to compensate for it.  On top of that, there is the fact that the acceleration is reported as a discrete quantity, so there is necessarily some approximation error as well as noise even if you do not go outside of the window.  When you add all of those factors together, some amount of drift is inevitable.

Comment: Interesting. I know my game area in advance, and that's gonna be around 3m x 3m, say 10 feet x 10 feet, and my precision only needs to be 1m (3 feet). When I walk holding the iphone I'm getting similar values for the same distances, so I'm guessing it's only a matter of multiplying by a constant value (I did these experiments by only considering positive areas of velocity over time graphs).   So basically what screws everything up is that negative peak I always get after a positive one.

Comment: What I'm now considering is to keep the first "big peak" I get and discard the next one. That would allow me, in theory, to both find in which the direction I'm moving and my current displacement.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you move any object in one direction, there's a force involved which accelerates the object.

To make the object come to a halt again, the same force is needed in the exact opposite direction - or to be more precise, the vector of the acceleration event that happened before needs to be multiplied with `-1`. That's your negative peak.

Not strictly a programming answer, but then again, your question is not strictly a programming question :)

Comment: Yeah, that's what should happen. What I notice is that deacceleration is such that it brings velocity down to negative values, which shouldn't really happen. My question is: does that normally happen with cheap accelerometers (like the one the iphone is provided with) or is that probably due to errors in my code?

Comment: Phew - from here on, I can only speculate: Maybe the small mass within the accelerometer, which is used to measure the forces is subject to resonance or some sort of elasticity related effects, which make it move beyond the neutral position after an abrupt stop... We're not quite dealing with precision instruments here. If the peak has a duration of n > 1 times the updating frequency, I think you can rule calculation / digitalization errors straight out. Is the peak large compared to the expected change in velocity?

Comment: The peak in question depends on how abruptly I stop. It doesn't need to /that/ abrupt, though. Sometimes it's just as large as the area of the positive peak, and that has disastrous effects in my calculation, other times it is significantly smaller.

Comment: Just to make sure - are we talking about an actual peak here, meaning the velocity becomes negative and then returns to zero or does it stay at the negative value (a negative plateau, in a sense)?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the confusion. I simply get a curve in the negative axis (I'm talking about the velocity over time graph). Depending on how sudden I come to a stop, this curve might have a high or a modest local minimum. In the former case I often get negative values for the change in movement, even though the cell phone is actually moving in the positive direction, whereas in the latter case I only notice a smaller change in displacement.

Answer (score 0):

If it's going a thousand miles per hour, its acceleration is 0. If it's speeding, the acceleration is positive. If it's slowing down, the acceleration is negative.

You can use the absolute number of the velocity to invert any negative acceleration, if that's needed:

```
fabs(delta_v); // use abs for ints
```

Comment: The physics of it all is clear, I just can't explain why I get pretty much each positive peak in velocity is followed by a negative one (of variable size). In practice, not only does the velocity go to zero when I decelerate while maintaining the same direction, it also goes to negative values before going back to zero again.

Comment: Hm, you get that result ("pretty much each positive peak in velocity is followed by a negative one") while moving the device faster and faster in a direction? Does the negative acceleration register properly when changing the moving speed of the device to a stop? If you experience a discrepancy peak when going from 0-5 mph, I would expect a similar reverse peak when going from 5-0 mph?

Comment: Here's a simple example: I take one step forward. In the corresponding direction I get first a positive peak of velocity, which is correct, immediately followed by a negative one when I decelerate. The acceleration values seem just about right. I think this is due to what JeremyP said, namely the trapezoidal rule with which I calculate the change in velocity.
I experience the same behavior when moving in the opposite direction and then come to a stop: a negative peak in velocity followed by a positive one.